# Hide / show div with initial partial viewing

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/7RDBk/1/

Currently I have a slideUp and slideDown functions to hide and show a div. I'm trying to get 25px showing initially before it expands and goes back to 25px on click. I would have thought this would be straight forward but I cant seem to find a way to check an attribute on the if statement to check whether it has expanded or not before knowing whether to slide up or not.

```
 if($(this).prev().is(':hidden') == true) { ..
```

i.e change to

```
 if($(this).prev().height() == 25) { ..
```

I've checked for CSS attributes and overflow but these dont seem to work. I cant really add classes at this point or wrap it any parent div, is it possible with these two divs as per fiddle?

Comment: `" I'm trying to get 25px showing initially before it expands and goes back to 25px on click "`. I'm lost at this point.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle (see: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDBk/2/), the "Show Less". text will be displayed now. (you were missing a semi colon)

Comment: The semi colon doesn't really matter.

Comment: I appreciate that (hence the +1) it doesn't in this instance, but when code gets copied it helps to use the correct syntax, I've seen too many projects where items have been copied without noticing the syntax errors and they lead to further problems down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing is by using jQuery's functions `animate` and `data`, for example

http://jsfiddle.net/H9LzU/

```
$('.readMoreTrigger').click(function () {
     if ($('.readMoreContent').data('shown')) {
         $(this).text('Read more..');
         $('.readMoreContent').animate({
             "height": "25px"
         }, 'fast');
         $('.readMoreContent').data('shown',false);
     } else {
         $(this).text('Read less..');
         $('.readMoreContent').animate({
             "height": $('.readMoreContent').data("orig_height")
         }, 'fast');
         $('.readMoreContent').data('shown',true);
     }
     /*$('.readMoreContent').slideUp('fast');
        if($(this).prev().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).prev().slideDown('fast');
            $(this).text('Read less..')
        }*/
 });
 /*$('.readMoreContent').hide();*/
 $('.readMoreContent').data("orig_height", $('.readMoreContent').css("height")).css({
     height: "25px"
 });
```

Comment: Nice, I didnt realise data could be used like this. Thanks.